# How is AES implemented in CryptoJS?

Tags: python, aes, cryptojs

I want to verify that CryptoJS's AES is actually implementing AES. However, I am not able to verify it by encrypting a plain using CryptoJS and decrypting the cipher with a python script using PyCrypto.

Source for CryptoJS:

http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/cryptogs
https://script.google.com/d/1IEkpeS8hsMSVLRdCMprij996zG6ek9UvGwcCJao_hlDMlgbWWvJpONrs/edit?usp=sharing

I gathered that in CryptoJS-AES,

1. it does 1 iteration of MD5 on the passphrase to generate the symmetric key.
2. In the cipher, the first 16bytes is the salt in the form of "Salted__[8byte random]".
3. The salt is used as the iv for the encryption/decryption.
4. done in CBC-Mode

The cipher is created with the below code in Google App Script.

```
var encryptedMessage = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt ('this is my message to be encrypted', '0123456789abcdef').toString();
//var decryptedMessage = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt (encryptedMessage, '0123456789abcdef').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

I then tried to decrypt the cipher with the below python code. (adapted from some stackoverflow thread)

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key): 
        self.bs = 16
        self.key = hashlib.md5(key.encode()).digest()
        self.key = key

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:])).decode("utf-8")

    def _pad(self, s):
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)

    @staticmethod
    def _unpad(s):
        print s
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]

key = "0123456789abcdef"
aes = AESCipher(key)
cipher = "U2FsdGVkX1/CuZIB2c+sxY7rA0jw19EOKrL87cU1bzwU9BlIDP6VZvsSzXAQ+6v8S2GQOzf4VpEw7AK0LSFfKw=="
bbb = aes.decrypt(cipher)
print bbb #prints out gibberish
```

How can i verify that the AES is correct? Or what have i done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

CryptoGS is a direct port of CryptoJS and you can find the CryptoJS AES implementation at the following link:
https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/aes.js

CryptoGS' code is minified but the following gist breaks up some of the encryption algos into separate sections:
https://gist.github.com/DimuDesigns/5666e9c6df531b8d11099dfd291ed0e4

You can try running the AES algo in the gist through a code beautfier and comparing the two.