# Why this cCryptoGS AES encryption gives out all ciphertext pretty much the same?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, encryption, aes

I'm currently experimenting AES encryption using Google App Script, and I found out about cCryptoGS.

It feels weird, as like all ciphered texts seem to start with **U2FsdGVkX1** (even though I change the part *this is my passphrase* in the example to something else *very very* different). I am not sure if I remembered correctly, I once tried AES in the past, but on Nodejs, and it looked just so much different, I'll get completely different text ciphered out *even if I change only a single character* in either my message, or my key.

Even in this post [How is AES implemented in CryptoJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285959/how-is-aes-implemented-in-cryptojs), the ciphered text also starts with **U2FsdGVkX1**.

What I am asking is this: Is this **cCryptoGS** actually do what it claims to do? (i.e to apply AES encryption to a message)

Here's the website https://ramblings.mcpher.com/gassnippets2/cryptojs-libraries-for-google-apps-script/ There are also graphs on the site to show that Google App Script cannot handle complicated calculations well, so it looks *legit*, but the result seems to be so... weird... Since, overall AES seemed to be one of the best option to do encryption.

If this is indeed how AES should work, is there any way that I can make it seems *more* random? Thank you so much in advance, :(

Thank you very much in advance,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What is U2FsdGVkX1?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8776/what-is-u2fsdgvkx1)

Comment: @andrewjames Thank you very much, yup, it does answer my question. :*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CryptoJS can process both passphrases and keys for encryption and decryption. Strings are interpreted as passphrases, `WordArray`s as keys, s. [*The Cipher Input*](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).
cCryptoGS wraps the passphrase variant and supports the algorithms AES, DES, TripleDES and Rabbit, see [*Usage*](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/gassnippets2/cryptojs-libraries-for-google-apps-script/#Usage).

E.g. for AES, cCryptoGS/CryptoJS encrypts with AES-256, whereby a passphrase must be passed in addition to the plaintext.
Before encryption a random 8 bytes salt is generated and from passphrase and salt a 32 bytes key and 16 bytes IV is derived with the OpenSSL key derivation function [`EVP_BytesToKey()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html).
The result is generated in OpenSSL format for compatibility with OpenSSL, which consists of the ASCII encoding of *Salted__* followed by the 8 bytes salt and the actual ciphertext, with the entire expression Base64 encoded.
The Base64 encoding of *Salted__* is U2FsdGVkX18=, where U2FsdGVkX1 is fixed (the last two characters depend on the 1st byte of the salt and can therefore change). Thus, any encryption starts with U2FsdGVkX1, but this does not reveal any information.
So yes, it is encrypted with AES-256, and the constant prefix U2FsdGVkX1 is not critical.

However, the key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()` is deemed insecure nowadays, especially with the parameters used by cCryptoGS/CryptoJS (broken MD5 digest and an iteration count of 1), s. e.g. [here, 3rd part](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29139), so its use cannot actually be recommended (apart for compatibility maybe).
This applies to the wrapped functionalities that use passphrases for encryption/decryption. cCryptoGS also *directly* allows the use of CryptoJS functions, see [*CryptoJS direct*](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/gassnippets2/cryptojs-libraries-for-google-apps-script/#CryptoJS_direct), whose security is to be assessed individually.

The secure way is to pass key and IV *directly*, or when using a passphrase not to apply the built-in function `EVP_BytesToKey()`, but a reliable key derivation function like PBKDF2.
These variants are supported by CryptoJS, but apparently not by cCryptoGS, at least not by the wrapped functionalities.

Also note that at least the linked cCryptoGS sources seem to be based on CryptoJS version 3.1.2 which is from 2013, s. [*cCryptoGS sources*](https://script.google.com/d/1IEkpeS8hsMSVLRdCMprij996zG6ek9UvGwcCJao_hlDMlgbWWvJpONrs/edit?usp=sharing) (current CryptoJS version is 4.1.1).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've read what you wrote like 5 times, I think I can somehow get it. Now I settle down with sjcl, which to tell the truth I'm happy as a clam to come across. Now I can set the IV to be random by my choice. I do have one small last question though, the IV must be exactly 16 bytes right? I did search and know this IVString is to use as the 'fake' first block to do XOr on the real first block. However, on messing around with it, I realized that I can set the IVString to be as long as 24 bytes (but some of the last characters in my IVString got change automticly?).

Comment: @user49685 - This can hardly be answered without more information. You should ask a new question with sample code and all the information needed to answer it. The fact is that the IV for AES is _exactly_ 16 bytes. If you can specify 24 bytes, it may be because the IV is Base64 encoded, your implementation or the library silently truncates the IV, etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I think I got it now. I think the library does truncate the IV or do some masking with it, because I just messed around by setting the IV straight to be some 24 bytes block, I did not implement anything. Ok, so if the IV is exactly 16 bytes, then, no more messing around =))) thank you very much, :*